# IP forwarding with iptables

Tags: ssh, nat, iptables

Suppose there are hosts `A` and `B`. `A` is allowed SSH access to `B` based on its IP address. Consider now another host `C`. `C` does not have access to `B`, but if we could route its traffic through `A`, then `C` could access `B`. The problem is, how to do this kind of address translation? No two hosts are on the same LAN.

My first thought was to do SNAT with iptables on `A`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --protocol tcp --source C --destination B --sport 7777 --dport 22 -j SNAT A
```

meaning that `C` should try to connect to `A:7777` but I realized that routing the packet before SNAT spoils everything, therefore address translation should be done in PREROUTING -- which unfortunately is impossible. Another thought was to set up a VPN, but I think it is too complicated. Is there a neat way to do this, preferably with something as clean as iptables?

Comment: You need dual NAT -- destination NAT before routing and source NAT after routing. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/443586/94136) for an example of dual NAT.